# Prevent scroll to top before router navigate to another page when using angular 2 router resolve

Tags: angular, scroll, angular2-routing, infinite-scroll

I have a div tag with router link. When click div tag, it should navigate to another page. Also I am using router Resolve to fetch data before router activated.

```
{ path: 'conversation/:id', component: InboxDetailComponent, resolve: { conversation: InboxConversationResolver }}
```

This is how div tag is appearing.

```
<div class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let conversation of conversations; let j = index;" [routerLink]="['/app/inbox/detail',conversation.items[0].id]"></div>
```

Everything is working fine except one thing. When click div tag, page scrolls to top before navigate to another page. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exactly same problem, but then i remembered I implemented the following in my app.component's constructor:

```
this.router.events.subscribe(
        () => window.scrollTo(0, 0)
    );
```

All I had to to was wait for the NavigationEnd event, instead of scrolling to the top on the first event that came through. So I implemented it like this:

```
this.router.events.subscribe((evt) => {
        if (!(evt instanceof NavigationEnd)) {
            return;
        }
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    });
```